# Cannot Convert in_addr to Unsigned Int in Socket Programming for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm building a reverse echo server in TCP using c++.

My problem occurs when I run my client.

When I compile my client.cpp, I get this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘in_addr’ to ‘in_addr_t {aka unsigned int}’ in assignment
  serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = *((struct in_addr*)host->h_addr);
```

This is my code for creating a connection:

```
serverName = argv[1];
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
struct hostent* host;
host = gethostbyname(serverName);

memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = *((struct in_addr*)host->h_addr);
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
memmove(&serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);

connectValue = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: @JerryCoffin that would be wrong, since `h_addr` is a pointer to an `in_addr` struct, not a pointer to an `in_addr_t` integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a whole `in_addr` struct instance to a single integer.  That will not work.

The `sockaddr_in::sin_addr` member is an `in_addr` struct, and the `in_addr::s_addr` member is the actual IP address.  Just drop the `s_addr` part to assign the whole `in_addr` struct as-is:

```
serverAddress.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)host->h_addr);
```

Otherwise, you can `memcpy()` (or, in your example, `memmove()`) the `in_addr` struct into the `sin_addr` member as a whole.  You are trying to copy/move to its `s_addr` member instead, so just drop that:

```
memcpy(&serverAddress.sin_addr, host->h_addr, host->h_length);
```

Comment: Worked great! s_addr was the problem. Thanks!